# PNG file is not valid error when reading path from DB but works if the path is hardcoded

Tags: php, mysql, image-processing, png, imagemagick

I run PHP 5.2 on Ubuntu with Apache 2.

When I want to serve a PNG file from PHP file which is hardcoded (using `$imgname`), I can succeed. However if I change the `$imgname` to `$imgdbname`, the browser fails and says it is not a valid PNG file.

```
$imgname = "cachepics/c3s9taopkp.png";
$imgdbname = readfromdb();

header("Content-type: image/png");
print file_get_contents($imgname);
```

However if I comment the `header("Content-type: image/png");` line, browser shows the all PNG garbage text in both cases. Therefore, I am sure the PHP instance is able to reach that file by reading the path from DB.

The ouput of

```
print "-".$imgname."-".$imgdbname."-";
```

seems exactly the same.

```
-cachepics/c3s9taopkp.png-cachepics/c3s9taopkp.png-
```

I will go crazy and don't know why the db version does not work.

Comment: What does the `readfromdb` function look like? Does it return the string or does it echo it?

Comment: It reads the database and returns the path. $imgdbname = $imgname = cachepics/c3s9taopkp.png

Comment: If the same exact string is stored in both `$imgname` and `$imgdbname`, then it should work. Try something like `var_dump($imgname); var_dump($imgdbname);` to verify that they are exactly the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the problem is that readfromdb have errors and generate warnings, printing these warning to STDIO, adding garbage to the resulting image, or aborting any later header (like content-type).
You could probably check the server error log for that (any warning of the style 'header can't be added, because already printed in file..'),  or test if both resulting files are the same size.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the reason why you get this problem, but please use `readfile` to directly output the contents of a file in PHP.